Talend Data Load Issue (DataStage)
Please help with the below scenario

I have incoming file data which I need to load to a Oracle DB.
There are around 1200 fields/columns in the table (the data from file has to be fed to these columns)
There are multiple fields that are not matching the field width criteria of the column. As an example, there is a field TransactionDescription, in the DB it's defined varchar200 but the data is 240 character long. I need the data to be automatically truncated to 200 characters before loading to the DB.

In DataStage it happens automatically, the data automatically is truncated and fed into the DB. In Talend the Job is failing. Is there a setting in Talend which can help here? Please note there are multiple columns here and hence I don't want to use functions like substring, truncate, cast etc.

You should use tSchemaComplianceCheck. There is an option : "Trim the excess content of column when length checking chosen and the length is greater than defined length"
